# similar platform to Scratch - any idea?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, text-processing

For several weeks I have been looking for an idea for a master's project.

I would like to build a platform similar to Scratch, but I do not want to build a regular program from ready-made blocks, and I would like to focus more on a specific field (e.g. build a neural network from blocks, speech sentizer, text processing).

However, I have no idea what exactly could be built from these blocks.

Maybe some of you have an idea for the IT branch, where you could use a graphic building tool.
The platform's goal should also have an educational element.

Answer (score 0):

[Deep Cognition](https://deepcognition.ai/features/) is very similar to what you're trying to achieve. You might be interested in some of the techniques like [code generation](https://tomassetti.me/code-generation/). I suggest you start with a deep-learning framework such as `pyTorch` and `keras` etc as your backend, a single category of data e.g. Images.

After deciding those some sort of initial GUI and code generation you'll get to your first tool and then on wards you can extend the tool to support multiple things, such as multi-modal data, multiple backends, fancy GUI.